# Drawing pie charts using CorePlot

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-plot

I finally somehow managed to add coreplot framework to my project.
Is there any documentation available on how to use it?.I googled it but couldnt get it.
And all the examples i found on the net are bar charts but i want the actual pie charts with that circle and wedges.Can i draw these using coreplot?

Are there any other ways i could draw these pie charts for my application.

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple `view` (subclass `UIView` and override `drawrect:`)

The delegate provides a value between 0 and 1.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat endAngle=([self.delegate giveCompletion]+0.75)*2*M_PI;

    UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.center radius:self.bounds.size.width/(3) startAngle:0.75*2*M_PI endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
    [path addLineToPoint:self.center];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y+self.bounds.size.width/(3)) ];
    [path addClip];
    [[UIColor blueColor]setFill];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
}
```

This allows you to produce a simple pie graph. You could construct a view which asks its delegate for an `NSArray` of values and subsequently draws a pie chart (similar to the method used in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

Core Plot includes API documentation and several example apps that show what it can do. The Plot Gallery app is a good place to start. It has several different pie charts and examples of all of the supported plot types.